# Spring - how to set the period interval of ScheduledTimerTask?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, spring-mvc, timer

My `xml` configuration will be ,

```
    <bean id="producer" class="com.pointel.T_Server.service.Producer" />

<bean id="timerTaskFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.scheduling.timer.MethodInvokingTimerTaskFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="producer"></property>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="executeListener"></property>
</bean>



    <bean id="timerTask" class="org.springframework.scheduling.timer.ScheduledTimerTask" singleton="true">
        <property name="timerTask" ref="timerTaskFactoryBean"></property>
        <property name="delay" value="5000"></property>
        <property name="period" value="60000"></property>
    </bean>



    <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.timer.TimerFactoryBean">
        <property name="scheduledTimerTasks">
            <list>
                <ref local="timerTask"></ref>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

In `spring` controller , I am updating the period as ,

```
org.springframework.scheduling.timer.ScheduledTimerTask timer = (org.springframework.scheduling.timer.ScheduledTimerTask)xmlWebApplicationContext.getBean("timerTask");
System.out.println("Period Before :"+timer.getPeriod()); // prints 60000
timer.setPeriod(5000);
System.out.println("Delay After :"+timer.getPeriod()); // prints 5000
```

But the time interval period is not affected to execute the target method.

It again runs for every 60 seconds only.

Why my update didn't affect the interval ?